# Laravel return value to the same view

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, laravel-5.3

Hello i am new with laravel so i decide to start  with sample examples so i start whit calculator programme: here is the strecture of my application

- calc.blade.php => contain the form that send data to calc/calc with POST methode
  `<form method="POST" action="calc/calc">`
- route.php => `Route::controller('calc', 'calcController');`
- calcController.php => contain 2 methods:

  1) getCalc() used with get to send the form `return view('calc');`

  2) postCalc(calcRequest $r) this methode do the traitement and return the result
  `return view('calc')->with('res',$res) ;`

the application work but the problem is that everytime i clic en send from the form **calc/calc is added to the URL**
for Exemple :

First operation      url is http://localhost/calcul/public/calc/calc

second operation url is http://localhost/calcul/public/calc/calc/calc

third operation    http://localhost/calcul/public/calc/calc/calc/calc

What is the problem and how could i fix it

thnks

Comment: change `<form method="POST" action="calc/calc">` to `<form method="POST" action="calc">`

Comment: thnk u so much it work now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" action="calc/calc">
```

That action is calling a relative path, so it will always add an extra /calc on the end of each URL.

To stay on the same URL you can use:

```
<form method="POST" action="/calc/calc">
```

Additionally, you may want to use the laravel URL helper function to keep it nicer and future proof:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-url